# Why I am not able to merge two data frames on a column containing some non-similar entries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
train.head()


    date    date_block_num  shop_id item_id item_price  item_cnt_day
    0             02.01.2013    0   59  22154   999.00  1.0          
    1             03.01.2013    0   25  2552    899.00  1.0          
    2             05.01.2013    0   25  2552    899.00  -1.0         
    3             06.01.2013    0   25  2554    1709.05 1.0          
    4             15.01.2013    0   25  2555    1099.00 1.0

test.head()

    ID  shop_id item_id
    0   0   5   5037
    1   1   5   5320
    2   2   5   5233
    3   3   5   5232
    4   4   5   5268
```

I want to add the item_price column to my test data frame from my train data frame so I am trying to merge the two data frames on “item_id”, 
‘item_id’ contains almost 90% similar values in both the data frames but getting a weird result

```
df=pd.merge(test[['item_id']],train[['item_price','item_id']],on='item_id',how='inner’)
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 60732252 entries, 0 to 60732251
    Data columns (total 2 columns):
    item_id       int64
    item_price    float64
    dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
    memory usage: 1.4 GB
```

Can anybody please help me that what is happening and how may I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is problem with duplicates.

One possible solution is remove them:

```
test = test.drop_duplicates('item_id')
train= train.drop_duplicates('item_id')
```

... or add helper columns for merge:

```
test['g'] = test.groupby('item_id').cumcount()
train['g'] = train.groupby('item_id').cumcount()

df=pd.merge(test[['item_id', 'g']],
            train[['item_price','item_id', 'g']],on=['item_id', 'g']).drop('g', axis=1)
```

Comment: They both are not working in first one I cannot drop duplicates as I have to use that test set to predict on my model afterwards and in the next helper column part it is only returning the unique values merged.

Comment: @VaibhavSka - Then seems I dont understand, what need. If in sample data change `item_id` in last 3 values to `2552` what is expected output after merge? Can you add it to question? Or can you create  [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What I exactly want is to have all my items which are in the test data frame to have a price tag also which has not been given in the dataframe, so what I m trying is to see that for those items which are present in the train data frame I would copy their prices to my test set and for those which are not present just leave them Nan or 0.

Comment: @VaibhavSka - Thank you for explanation, but still not sure if understand. Is provlem create expected output from sample data, if change last 3 values of column `item_id` to `2552` Because I am sample man, sorry.